# Login via Ajax doesn't work with Laravel (session lost)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, authentication, session

I'm trying to login a user by Ajax with the `Auth::attempt` method.

```php
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $datas['user_email'], 'password' => $datas['user_password']])) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $request->session()->save();

    return response()->json(['success' => $response_object]);
}
```

The method returns true and after an `Auth::check()`, I can see that the user is logged in. But on ajax success, I redirect with js with `window.location.href` and the user is not logged in anymore.

My get and post routes use the `StartSession` middleware.

I don't have any errors and really don't know how to proceed.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Where do you redirect?

Comment: To another page on same site [Lajos Arpad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436560/lajos-arpad)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , you are trying to login using the js , the request reach the server and you login the user and **Regenerate** the session , that means there is a new  session ID for the user after **login** , but I think that the browser still use the previous session data when it sends requests to the server. try not to generate the session and see if the problem still exists, or try to replace the session cookie in the browser with the new one.

Comment: Hi Ali,

Thanks, I tried setting the laravel_session cookie with the new one but the user is still not logged after page reload :/ Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: @jamaicv did you try not to regenerate the session at all after login?

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax request is using the API routes then there won't be a session, maybe is the problem.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-ajax-request-dont-set-session-variable#reply-447467

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).